# Nginx over apache gives 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: 14.04, server, apache2, proxy, nginx

I'm trying to run Nginx over Apache.

My configuration is that I set Apache to listen to port `8080` instead of `80`.

Then I set Nginx to proxy all requests to the same domain over port `8080`:

```
upstream app {
    server example.com:8080;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;

    charset utf-8;

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    access_log off;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/example.com-error.log error;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

        proxy_pass https://app/;
        proxy_redirect off;

        # Handle Web Socket connections
        proxy_http_version 1.0;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }
}
```

Then I setup the Apache configuration, which seems to work just fine, cause I can access my site at http://example.com:8080 without problems.

```
<VirtualHost *>
    DocumentRoot "/home/forge/example.com"
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/example_com_access.log common
    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/example_com_error.log

        <Directory /home/forge/example.com/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
        </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

But when trying to go to http://example.com/ I get `502 Bad Gateway - nginx/1.8.0`.

Any ideas how to fix this?

The reason I need this is that I have one web server which holds a lot of websites using Nginx, but I need some (only some of them) of the sites to run Apache rules instead of Nginx rules.

I am running Ubuntu `14.04`.

**EDIT**: Here is the log from `/var/log/nginx/error.log`:

```
2015/11/06 11:05:27 [emerg] 18176#0: "proxy_pass" cannot have URI part in location given by regular expression, or inside named location, or inside "if" statement, or inside "limit_except" block in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/thehostboy.com:71
2015/11/06 11:07:49 [emerg] 18564#0: "proxy_pass" cannot have URI part in location given by regular expression, or inside named location, or inside "if" statement, or inside "limit_except" block in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/thehostboy.com:71
2015/11/06 11:23:25 [notice] 21045#0: signal process started
2015/11/06 11:23:25 [alert] 20875#0: *60679 open socket #4 left in connection 9
2015/11/06 11:23:25 [alert] 20875#0: *60680 open socket #41 left in connection 10
2015/11/06 11:23:25 [alert] 20875#0: *60678 open socket #46 left in connection 25
2015/11/06 11:23:25 [alert] 20875#0: *60677 open socket #45 left in connection 26
2015/11/06 11:23:25 [alert] 20875#0: aborting
2015/11/06 11:25:04 [notice] 21184#0: signal process started
2015/11/06 11:25:04 [alert] 21052#0: *97 open socket #3 left in connection 5
2015/11/06 11:25:04 [alert] 21052#0: *98 open socket #36 left in connection 11
2015/11/06 11:25:04 [alert] 21052#0: aborting
2015/11/06 11:27:02 [notice] 21294#0: signal process started
2015/11/06 11:28:39 [notice] 21378#0: signal process started
```

Comment: Check the `/var/log/nginx/error.log` file for the exact failure reason - start there and add the log here if you want us to look at it more

Comment: try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21662940/proxy-pass-cannot-have-uri-part-in-location

Comment: @ThomasW., I just cleared the log and restarted `nginx`. And the only thing that comes into it is the line ending with `signal process started`, and it comes from restarting `nginx`. Nothing is logged for the Bad Gateway.

Comment: Thanks @Lety, but I am quite sure this error was from when I had `location /* { ... }` while back when I tried anything in order to get it to work. It is also a report from long time ago, and `nginx` have been restarted many times since that.

Comment: Solved changing `proxy_pass` to `http://...` instead of `https://...`. Feel stupid now... Thanks anyways guys.

Comment: @Mark post that as an answer to your question so you can accept it and mark the question as answered later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed this by changing `proxy_pass` from `https://...` to `http://...`.